# Change objects attribute names on runtime

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of objects like this:

```
 var nodes = [{"size":8,"name":"myName"},{"size":10,"name":"otherName"},{"size":11,"name":"userName"}];
```

How do I create an array `arr` that contains objects mapped from `nodes` but that the attributes have different names. Say I want that `arr.r` be mapped to each `size` attribute, so:

```
thisSize = arr[0].r
```

should assing `8` to `thisSize`.
Hope I explained my question clearly.

Comment: So you want to create an array like `[{r:8}, {r:10}, ... ]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use properties or `map` if you're not worried about supporting Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, but I'll assume you are. Just iterate and construct a new array with new objects:

```
var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];

    arr.push({
        r: node.size
    });
}
```

Map your properties in the object `push`ed as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script>
    function item(name,size){
      this.name = name;
      this.size = size;
    }

    var arr = [];
    arr[0] = new item("item 1",9);
    arr[1] = new item("item 2",14);

    alert("name: " + arr[0].name + " size:" + arr[0].size);
    alert("name: " + arr[1].name + " size:" + arr[1].size);
    </script>
```

Comment: And what exactly did that demonstrate...?

Comment: shows how to create an object on an array.. pretty obvious I thought. and useful if he didn't know. IT community these days sheesh.

Comment: The question was pretty obvious too, I thought. And this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I personally would welcome all forms of information relational to subject.

Comment: I would too. *And this has nothing to do with it.*